# Properly design project with many constants in C++

Tags: c++, constants

On our current project, we are currently having issues with the way we are handling constants. To try to sum it up, let's say we have different action types, defined as const std::string

```
const std::string actionTypeX = "XXX";
const std::string actionTypeY = "YYY";
...
```

Those action types may have different properties, which makes them trigger different behavior. This is usually implemented through an std::unordered_map, linking the action type to whatever property we need :

```
const std::unordered_map<std::string, int> actionFlow = {
{ actionTypeX, DB_FLOW },
{ actionTypeY, DRL_FLOW },
 .... };
```

Those maps are usually used in one single implementation, so we put them in anonymous namespaces in the corresponding CPP file. On the opposite, the constants strings are usually used by many files and so are defined in a common constants file.

The issue we have is that we end up having the infamous static initialization order fiasco: Some maps are using common strings that are not yet initialized, generation a segmentation fault.

The known solution for this issues are:

- Put all maps that depends on those constants in the same file, thus avoiding the problem of the order. But this would create a huge, ugly file which might be difficult to maintain
- Put those maps within a static function returning a reference to a static map, but in my opinion it does look a bit 'hacky'

While both solutions should work, I feel they would just be a workaround for a design problem of our application.

So my question is, how should a C++ program with many constants be designed so it is easily maintainable ?

Thank you,

Regards,

Comment: You could *generate* the C++ file initializing the map

Comment: First question: why are they **strings**? If they are so key to your application, don't they deserve to be, well, more than strings? At least enums or something?

Answer (score 3):

How about not using std::string for constants:

```
constexpr auto actionTypeX = "XXX";
```

By using constexpr you no longer face the issues related to static intialization fiasco. You can then safely use this constants to initialize your maps.
Furthermore, you can then use std::string_view as the keys (that's assumed you only use the global constants as the keys anyway) in the maps to get some more flexibility and keep the maps lightweight.

Answer (score 1):

> Put those maps within a static function returning a reference to a static map, but in my opinion it does look a bit 'hacky'

I would go with this approach, but possibly encapsulate it a bit more. It seems like the `std::unordered_map` is an implementation detail, and all you need to expose is the access to the constants.

**Library:**
A little helper that hides the static initialization can be useful. You would put this in a header to include whenever you need to define constants:

```
// T = value, Init = functor to initialize constants
template <typename T, typename Init>
class Constants
{
    static std::unordered_map<std::string, T>& constants()
    {
        static bool initialized = false;
        static std::unordered_map<std::string, T> map;

        if (!initialized) // alternative: map.empty()
            Init()(map);

        return map;
    }

public:
    static T get(const std::string& key)
    {
        return constants()[key];
    }
};
```

**Constant definition:**
In a concrete .cpp file, you could use it as follows:

```
// Your function for initialization
struct ActionFlowInit
{
    void operator()(std::unordered_map<std::string, int>& map) const
    {
        map["one"] = 1;
        map["two"] = 2;
    }
};

using ActionFlows = Constants<int, ActionFlowInit>;
```

In a real scenario, you would expose the functor in the header, but leave the implementation of its `operator()` to the .cpp file, in order to abstract away the actual constants.

If you don't want to settle for `std::unordered_map`, the signature can of course be more generic -- just pass a parameter to `operator()` which allows you to register a constant.

**Constant usage:**
Access the constants like this:

```
int x = ActionFlows::get("one");
```

It's of course possible to add more syntactic sugar, especially for the initialization. `boost::list_of` can be an inspiration.